# magento newsletter_subscriber query

Tags: query

I'm trying to get update customers to subscribers in my custom table:

```
UPDATE `my_contacts_and_subscribers` AS `dc` LEFT JOIN `newsletter_subscriber` AS `ns` ON dc.customer_id = ns.customer_id SET `dc`.`is_subscriber` = 1, `dc`.`subscriber_status` = 1 WHERE (ns.subscriber_status =1)
```

However this query is hanging, not finishing. Is there anything wrong with it?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your SQL in a syntax checker and looks good. Try doing this using a SELECT statement first before running the UPDATE and strip it down to bare bones. Sorry I can't help without more info.

https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should always paste more information about your project in order to better understand it. Here schema structure is missing for ***my_contacts_and_subscribers*** table.

Try with following query:

```
UPDATE my_contacts_and_subscribers
SET is_subscriber = 1, subscriber_status = 1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM customer_entity 
    WHERE newsletter_subscriber.customer_id = my_contacts_and_subscribers.customer_id 
    AND newsletter_subscriber. subscriber_status = 1
);
```

Also, you've mentioned that it takes too long. How big are your tables ***my_contacts_and_subscribers*** and ***newsletter_subscriber***? Paste results of:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_contacts_and_subscribers;
SELECT count(*) FROM newsletter_subscriber;
```

And, at the end, you're maybe missing indexes, that's why join goes to slow. You can check your execution plan by putting word ***EXPLAIN*** in front of your query.

Check do you have index in ***my_contacts_and_subscribers*** on ***customer_id*** field. You can add it by executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `my_contacts_and_subscribers` ADD INDEX `idx_my_contacts_customer_id` (`customer_id`);
```

It can speed up this update query a lot.